# How to prevent the input field from accepting more than 2 decimal places in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Restrict input field from accepting more than 2 decimal places. In most of the places, This is recommended, But instead of validating later, I dont want to allow more than 2 decimal places in the input field itself.

```
var validate = function(e) {
          var t = e.value;
          e.value = (t.indexOf(".") >= 0) ? (t.substr(0, t.indexOf(".")) + t.substr(t.indexOf("."), 3)) : t;
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Enter the number</p>
    <input type="text" id="resultText" oninput="validate(this)" />
```

Comment: based on your code, this doesn't look like react native. It looks like React for the web

Comment: It is react native code and I have used javascript inside it for splitting upto 2 decimal places

Comment: React Native doesn't use script tags, or head tags or body tags or paragraph tags or input tags.....this is web code. RN uses <TextInput> instead of <input>. RN doesn't need a body tag or div tags, it uses <View> tags. RN doesn't use <p> either. It uses <Text>........‍♂️ Those tags you're using are web-tags. Remember React is done on the web. React Native is for phones

Answer (score 4):

You could try this.

Set up your state for the input: `const [value, setValue] = useState()`

Then in your `TextInput` callback `onChangeText`, set it up like this.

```
onChangeText={(text) => {
    const validated = text.match(/^(\d*\.{0,1}\d{0,2}$)/)
    if (validated) {
       setValue(text)
    }
}}
```

This validates a string first to match the following pattern:

1. zero or more digits
2. followed by 0 or 1 decimal place
3. followed by 0, 1, or 2 decimal places (but no more than 2)

I also start the regex with a ^ which forces the match to start at the beginning of the text.

The text argument that is passed in to `onChangeText` is the entire string (not just the next character). If this string doesn't conform to the regex we set up (validation) then we ignore this value and the state isn't updated.

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but this one worked for me.

Let me also add this: in React Native's TextInput you can control the keyboard type. Mine is set to a numeric keyboard so the user never gets a chance to enter a letter. This should work either way. It's just a side note

Answer (score 0):

```
<input pattern='d\+\.\d\d$'/>
```

You can specify a regex pattern on the input and tell it to only accept numbers (\d), along with a dot and only two numbers after the dot.

I have no idea if that works in react native, only in browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to resort to regex.

You can simply use conditionals of substrings on top of regex.

```
const onChangeText = (text) => {
  // Only allow "number & ." input
  const cleanNumber = text.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")

  // Only take first 2 values from split. Ignore the rest.
  const strAfterDot = cleanNumber.split('.', 2)[1] 

  if (strAfterDot.length <= 2){
    console.log("setValue now")
    setValue(text)
  } else {
    console.log("Should not be allowed. You can trim the value yourself.)
    const strBeforeDot = cleanNumber.split('.', 1)[0]
    setValue(strBeforeDot + '.' + strAfterDot.substr(0, 2))
  }
}
```

(Not tested for edge-cases, I'll leave that up to you.)